# php cURL return size increase

Tags: php, curl

I'm Currently proxying an endpoint by running a cURL however the size of my cURL is about 10 times larger than the original API, Why is that, and how can I decrease the size?  This is all JSON BTW.

`Original API return size = 32.2kb`
`cURL return size = 488KB`

And here is my cURL script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
// set url
$url = 'http://domain.com/api/v1';

// set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

Comment: hummmm I wonder ... `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: That didn't do anything.  I thought when you set that with an empty string it would act like a wildcard and just apply all?

Comment: @AlbertoVillacorta `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");` can reduce the size of the download in 3/4 (just tested it) . Please be gentle to whom is trying to help you.

Comment: @PedroLobito the original api return is 32.2kb and when I curl it, my return is 488kb.  My question is why is it so much bigger? and how can I decrease the size to reflect the size that the real api returns?  I'm not adding any data to it.

Comment: What do you mean by original api?

Comment: @PedroLobito:  That didn't mean to come off as sounding short.  I'm sorry if it did.  So I just tested that  and it didn't reduce the size at all for me.... very strange

Comment: If one response is 32KB and one is 488KB there should be some visible difference.  What is added in the second one, what API are you using?  Are you compressing the output from your server when you return the curl response?

Comment: There is an api that exists and it returns json data.  I'm just trying to curl it and return the same data.

Comment: can you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");` and `$cInfo =  curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $cInfo['size_download'];` before `curl_close`?  what's the size with and without gzip ?

Answer (score -1):

`ob_start('ob_gzhandler');`
php output buffer controll was the fix to my problem.  Thanks all that tried to help!